# Account linking error: "Can't parse the response. The response needs to be JSON format."

Tags: json, oauth, actions-on-google

**I am attempting account linking within 'Actions on Google'. Everything works until my OAuth provider responds to Google's request for tokens.**

**This is the JSON that is returned and appears to be properly formatted:**

```
{"access_token":"edeaa27e-12b7-43a1-bc7c-e6bbf9af71c3","expires_in":5184000.0,"refresh_token":"4344383b-cf07-4d12-a5c2-44b6481f5f48","token_type":"Bearer"}
```

**This is the error:**

```
{ "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.identity.accountlinking.type.AccountLinkingError", "errorReason": "Can't parse the response. The response needs to be JSON format.", "response": { ... }, "step": "AUTH_CODE_EXCHANGE" }
```

Details:

```
{
  "insertId": "-hgv4mfb4b",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.identity.accountlinking.type.AccountLinkingError",
    "errorReason": "Can't parse the response. The response needs to be JSON format.",
    "response": {
      "status": 200,
      "body": "{\"access_token\":\"cdd79134-316d-46ca-8d82-62fc7c35d905\",\"expires_in\":5184000.0,\"refresh_token\":\"fc63ceb3-0a8d-40ac-a1a3-a8cfab110bef\",\"token_type\":\"Bearer\"}"
    },
    "step": "AUTH_CODE_EXCHANGE"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "assistant_action_project",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "my-project"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-07-30T23:15:28.221Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/my-project/logs/accountlinking-pa.googleapis.com%2Ferror",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-07-30T23:15:28.676796217Z"
}
```

**Here is the response from my OAuth provider via curl. This is what Google gets. It looks like properly formatted JSON.**

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Vary: Accept
Vary: Accept
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:f494398c-ac65-47c8-84be-65aea2c190a4
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:f494398c-ac65-47c8-84be-65aea2c190a4
< X-HOST-nonce: 3eTaf/2/7riVVh24uAsUT+KHqcJPq0F2cw7C5ldMkMF4iH5rDbHQEgOp2OU9RaQFr/HjBBEpkKekcCxlmzek5g==
X-HOST-nonce: 3eTaf/2/7riVVh24uAsUT+KHqcJPq0F2cw7C5ldMkMF4iH5rDbHQEgOp2OU9RaQFr/HjBBEpkKekcCxlmzek5g==
< X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4.040 Win32NT/.NET
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4.040 Win32NT/.NET
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Tue, 03 Aug 2021 03:17:00 GMT
Date: Tue, 03 Aug 2021 03:17:00 GMT
< Content-Length: 155
Content-Length: 155
< x-HOST-proxy: true
x-HOST-proxy: true
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000

{"access_token":"6cff16ee-3b3e-4ecf-9664-51515ede6cc8","expires_in":5184000.0,"refresh_token":"03725df6-8d4c-434a-ab36-adedb43b76d7","token_type":"Bearer"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google will not accept the 'expires_in' value above, because it includes a decimal. Not sure if this impacts all values with a decimal or just '.0', but the OAuth spec doesn't seem to specifically exclude such a value. Javascript converts any float with just a 0 after the decimal to a whole number. My issue was that the 3rd party OAuth provider was returning a string including a float that Google would not parse as JSON.

Comment: The spec does now require a DIGIT in the 'expires_in' value, which may not include a decimal.